# "paris" tag not allowed because "pari" exists

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Someone asked a question ([How to make find and update query in Paris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248804/how-to-make-find-and-update-query-in-paris)) involving the [Idiorm and Paris toolkits](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/). When trying to add a [paris](/questions/tagged/paris) tag, it was blocked due to the existence of [pari](/questions/tagged/pari).

Since this is not a tag pluralization, could this tag be manually added, assuming that [idiorm](/questions/tagged/idiorm) and [paris](/questions/tagged/paris) are useful tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems reasonable to me. I created both tags on the question. Since you appear to be familiar with the toolkits, feel free to propose tag wikis for them.