# Is the tag pluralization filter working correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, plurals

For a long time, there's been a tag filter that blocks the creation of a "singular" tag if a "plural" of the same tag exists.  [Here's an example* of it working correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113391/135887).  Diamond mods can bypass it.

The other day, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17443678/revisions) created [rectangle](/questions/tagged/rectangle), while [rectangles](/questions/tagged/rectangles) exists already.

Earlier today, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17467431/revisions) created [http-header](/questions/tagged/http-header) while [http-headers](/questions/tagged/http-headers) exists already.

Is this change in behavior intentional, or is this a bug?  If it's intentional, was it documented somewhere?

To demonstrate the busted-ness, I've also added [plural](/questions/tagged/plural) to this question, where [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) already existed.

Comment: maybe it only works in one direction, i.e. you can't create tags which is the plural of an existing tag, but you can create a tag which is the singular form of an existing (plural) tag? Just a wild guess

Comment: That is possible, but it seems silly if so, and it isn't what I remember it doing.

Comment: I tried it the other way on this port earlier and it seemed to go through, so it doesn't seem to work as expected here in any case.

Comment: looking into it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix rolled out in release 2013.7.9.826. The checks were performed only on tags with approved synonyms.